# для чего нужен (-1) в Integer.parseInt(parts[4])-1

Tags: java, дата

```
public Person read() throws IOException {
    Person person = null;
    if (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        String s = fileScanner.nextLine();
        String[] parts = s.split(" ");

        String firstName = parts[1];
        String middleName = parts[2];
        String lastName = parts[0];

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(parts[5]),
                Integer.parseInt(parts[4])-1,
                Integer.parseInt(parts[3]));

        person = new Person(firstName, middleName, lastName, calendar.getTime());
    }
    return person;
}
```

это работа с месяцем, `Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar`, для чего вот `-1` только не пойму

Comment: обычно `-1` используется для уменьшения числа на единицу. Какую логику автор заложил в этот код я незнаю, но логично будет предположить что значение `parts[4]` выходит за некие рамки!

Comment: Если какой-то ответ ответы вас устраивает, то не забудьте принять его (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 6):

В данном случае вызывается конструктор:

[GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar(int,%20int,%20int))

Который вторым параметром принимает значение месяца. Причем в документации явно сказано, что счет месяцев идёт с 0 (то есть январь - это 0, а декабрь - 11).

Поэтому если с `fileScanner` значение месяца считывается как 1-12, то для приведения к формату 0-11 из него надо вычесть единицу.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы месяц был от 0 до 11, а не от 1 до 12.